# How to create specific number sequence using Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sequence

I have tried for hours to achieve the following with no success (see Desired results).

I attempted to start with the following code, but was stumped thereafter.

```
select c.LOAN
,year(c.ASOF_DATE) as [PAYMENT_YEAR],DATEPART(QUARTER,c.ASOF_DATE) as [PAYMENT_QUARTER]
,sum(c.PRIN+c.INTEREST) as [PAYMENT]
,(row_number() over(partition by c.loan order by c.loan,year(c.ASOF_DATE),DATEPART(QUARTER,c.ASOF_DATE))% 5) - 1
from CASHFLOW c
join LOANTAB l on
    l.LOAN = c.LOAN
where 
c.ASOF_DATE > '2018-06-30'
and not(l.LOAN_KIND like 'sfp%')
GROUP BY c.LOAN,year(c.ASOF_DATE),DATEPART(QUARTER,c.ASOF_DATE)
```

**Desired result**

```
LOAN    | PAYMENT  | YEAR
3750000 | 1000     | 0 
3750000 | 1000     | 1.1
3750000 | 1000     | 1.2 
3750000 | 1000     | 1.3
3750000 | 1000     | 1.4
3750000 | 10000    | 2.1
```

```
3766310 | 204009   | 0
3766310 | 204009   | 1.1
3766310 | 204009   | 1.2
3766310 | 204009   | 1.3
3766310 | 204009   | 1.4
3766310 | 204009   | 2.1
3766310 | 204009   | 2.2
3766310 | 204009   | 2.3
3766310 | 204009   | 2.4
3766310 | 204009   | 3.1
3766310 | 204009   | 3.2
3766310 | 204009   | 3.3
3766310 | 204009   | 3.4
3766310 | 204009   | 4.1
3766310 | 204009   | 4.2
3766310 | 204009   | 4.3
3766310 | 204009   | 4.4
3766310 | 204009   | 5.1
3766310 | 204009   | 5.2
3766310 | 204009   | 5.3
3766310 | 204009   | 5.4
3766310 | 67946.34 | 6.1
```

Comment: Note: Year is just the name of the column. It does not refer to a specific month. The goal is to create a number sequence like the one shown.

Comment: I don't understand the question you are asking.  Your query is returning multiple columns.  What does the original data look like?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the year column.

Comment: The columns of data are loan, as of date, interest, principal. Payment = principal + interest. I group by loan, year, and quarter. Additionally, I need a column that follows the sequence shown. The first record is always zero. The rest of the sequence is 1 - 4, with each subsequent 1-4 being added by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get assistance with my issue. The result was as follows:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#base' ,'u') is not null drop table #base
select c.LOAN
,year(c.ASOF_DATE) as [PAYMENT_YEAR],DATEPART(QUARTER,c.ASOF_DATE) as [PAYMENT_QUARTER]
,sum(c.PRIN+c.INTEREST) as [PAYMENT]
,(row_number() over(partition by c.loan order by c.loan,year(c.ASOF_DATE),DATEPART(QUARTER,c.ASOF_DATE))) as [ROWONE]
into #base
from CASHFLOW c
join LOANMAST l on
    l.LOAN = c.LOAN
where 
c.ASOF_DATE > '2018-06-30'
and not(l.LOAN_KIND like 'sfp%')
GROUP BY c.LOAN,year(c.ASOF_DATE),DATEPART(QUARTER,c.ASOF_DATE)


declare @LOAN varchar(20),@PAYMENT decimal(16,2),@rowone varchar(50)
declare @i int, @j int, @k int, @ploan varchar(50)
declare @t table (i int, j int,LOAN varchar(50),PAYMENT decimal(16,2),ROWONE varchar(50))
declare c cursor for select LOAN,PAYMENT,ROWONE from #base 
    --where loan in ('3715042','3716254','3722741','3726310') 
    order by 1, rowone
open c
fetch c into @LOAN,@PAYMENT,@rowone
select @i=0,@j=0,@ploan=''
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    if @loan<>@ploan begin select @ploan=@loan,@i=1,@j=1 end
    if @i=1 and @j=1
        insert into @t 
            select 0,0,@LOAN,@PAYMENT,@rowone
    insert into @t 
        select @i,@j,@LOAN,@PAYMENT,@rowone
    select @i=@i+1
    if @i>4 and @loan=@ploan begin select @j=@j+1,@i=1 end
    fetch c into @LOAN,@PAYMENT,@rowone
end
close c
deallocate c
select (case when convert(varchar,j)+'.'+convert(varchar,i)='0.0' then '0' else convert(varchar,j)+'.'+convert(varchar,i) end) CUSTOM,loan as [LOAN],payment as [PAYMENT] from @t order by 2,1

drop table #base
```